# phonegap/cordova create project says missing one of following

Tags: android, cordova

I've search around and saw a few question about this problem, but I have tried all the solution and I still can't create a project.

When running this code in `command prompt`:

```
create <project_folder_path> <package_name> <project_name>
```

the result is always:

```
Missing one of the following:
JDK: http://java.oracle.com
Android SDK: http://developer.android.com
Apache ant: http://ant.apache.org
```

I know there's already some question about this. I've already tried all the solution they give, but still no luck.

Followig the [guide](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.3.0/guide_getting-started_android_index.md.html#Getting%20Started%20with%20Android) and some solution for similar question, so far I've tried:

1. Check, double check, triple check the environment variables for PATH:

   - Java Development Kit (C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_10\bin)
   - Android SDK platform tools (D:\Development\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools)
   - Android SDK tools (D:\Development\Android\android-sdk\tools)
   - Apache ANT (D:\Development\apache-ant-1.8.4\bin)
2. Open command prompt and:

   - type: java -version (work - showing version 1.7.0_10)
   - type: javac -version (work - showing version 1.7.0_10)
   - type: ant -version (work - showing version 1.8.4)
   - type: adb (work)
   - type: android (work - launch android sdk manager)
3. use phonegap/cordova from [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/download) and from [Cordova](http://cordova.apache.org/#download)
4. make sure the folder path for `<project_folder_path>` is not exist
5. not using - in package name.

Comment: I'm assuming you're using Windows. Looks like you shouldn't be getting this error. Anyways, check this blog post, especially third problem: http://simonmacdonald.blogspot.com/2012/11/getting-create-command-to-work-on.html It might help.

Comment: Thank you, @keune. You're right, I'm using windows 7 64bit. I've already looked at the link along with the guide and still no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aside from adding JDK and Apache Ant in your PATH system variable, add two more system variables: JAVA_HOME (C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_10) and ANT_HOME (D:\Development\apache-ant-1.8.4).

Answer (score 1):

My Java home was pointing to JRE instead of JDK, Please check is JAVA_HOME is pointing to JDK. Check javac command is working.

Comment: I also had to add `%JAVA_HOME%\bin` to `PATH`. Checking `javac` is a good idea - the PhoneGap docs say only to check `java` which will work even if you only have the JRE installed.

Answer (score 1):

In my case then the path added 
;%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%ANT_HOME%\bin
did not replace any of the vars %JAVA_HOME% nor the %ANT_HOME% to the set value, even though they were set as system environment vars.

Solution was:

- Closed the nodejs prompt
- Started the nodejs prompt as admin
- c:> path

Path was now OK

- Closed the nodejs prompt
- Started the nodejs prompt - not as admin
- c:> path

Path was still OK

Why did it work just by starting as admin and then return back to normal? Maybe a bug somewhere in Win8.

Answer (score 0):

Following enviroment variables have to be working:

- java
- javac
- ant
- adb
- android

To see if they work press on your keyboard WINDOWS + r  both at the same time then type in "cmd". Then type in "java" for example, if it says it is not found, then you have to fix it.